# $\int_{0}^{1}\sin(k\pi x)\sin(j\pi x) = \int_{0}^{1}\sin^2(k\pi x)$ as $k,j : 1 \rightarrow \infty$?

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus

I wonder if anyone could give me a hint on how one could show or dismiss the equality of the following equation,

> $\int_{0}^{1}\sin(k\pi x)\sin(j\pi x) = \int_{0}^{1}\sin^2(k\pi x)=1/2\,\,\,\,\forall$ $k,j : 1 \rightarrow \infty$,

I am able to show that the equality holds for for $k=j \pm 1$, although I am somewhat stuck on how one would approach a more general solution and conclusion.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Dismiss: fix $k$ let $j \to \infty$, then $\int_{0}^{1}\sin(k\pi x)\sin(j\pi x) \to 0$ by Riemann-Lebesgue lemma, so it is not $= 1/2$ for all $j$.

Comment: for $k\neq j$, then integral is zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint.** Use the identity $$\sin(A)\sin(B)=\frac12\left[\cos(A-B)-\cos(A+B)\right]$$Make separate cases for when $k=j$ nd $k\ne j$.